# A page can only have one server-side form tag, but I need two

Tags: c#, asp.net

currently my ASP.NET web application is using a master page, nested master page and a content page. On the nested master page I have a content placeholder for navigational links, and another for the main content. The reason as to why I have two is because my main masterpage has already determined a fixed format for the rest of my pages, and I'm using nested masterpages because I need different types of navigational links for different roles used in my website. However, for the navigational links a LinkButton is used for the sign out button, thus it requires me to use a form tag with a runat="server" in order for me to be able to run the page. However, in my content page, I also need a form runat="server" tag for my main content. :-( Does anyone have an idea to propose on how to fix this problem? I want to stick to using multiple content placeholders so minor changes won't affect the entire page.

Anyways here's a snippet of my code from the masterpage

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="navigationlinks" runat="server">
<form id="navForm" runat="server">
    <a class="toggleMenu" href="#">
        <img src="images/nav_icon.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <ul class="nav" id="nav">
        <li class="current"><a href="UserHome.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="UserCompetition.aspx">Competition</a></li>
        <li><a href="UserGallery.aspx">Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"     href="#">Discussions
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="UserDiscussionCreate.aspx">Create Discussion</a></li>
                <li><a href="UserDiscussionView.aspx">View Discussion</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="UserSubmission.aspx">Submission</a></li>
        <li><a href="UserResults.aspx">Results</a></li>
        <li><a href="UserMyAccount.aspx">My Account</a></li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
</form>
```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content1" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

ContentPlaceHolder1 is used for the main content in the content page. So even with the form tag already in "navigationallinks" I'll need another form tag

Answer (score 1):

> in my content page, I also need a form runat="server" tag for my main content.

You already have it since this page have a masterpage which include server-side form tag!
When you have a masterpage with

```html
<form runat="server">...</form>
```

All pages using that masterpage will have the form, and no need to add it again in the page!

**Edit:**

Just remove all form tags inside any page or nested masterpage, and add it the masterpage wrapping all the elements.

Inside the masterpage that has the `<body>` tag, right after the body add the `<form runat="server">` tag and close it just before the `</body>`. And remove all the other form tags.

Comment: I added in some edits, adding the form tag in the navigationallinks content placeholder is not enough, i need it for contentplaceholder1 as well:-(

Comment: @user3763216 No you do not. Take a step back because if it's _formatting_ you are trying to solve, that has nothing to do with what you are asking for. And in any case, you can't _nest forms_ - whether it's asp.net or plain vanilla HTML.

Comment: @EdSF I tried removing it from my content page and i got this: Control 'Content1_ContentPlaceHolder1_tb_name' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: Then put it in your masterpage where the ContentPlaceHolder is within the form with runat="server". This is how most people do it.

Comment: use the form only inside the masterpage that serves other masterpages, wrapping all content. not inside nested masterpages. (updated the answer)